# how to implement scoped model to navigation screen when scoped model initialized in the previous screen and not in myApp()

Tags: flutter, dart, scoped-model

im trying to use scoped model in 2 screens in the app and i dont want to run the app with scoped model, i just initialize scoped model in first screen and it worked but i got an error in the second screen where i navigate to it. so what do i do?

first i call the first screen from the pre screen like this

```
Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => ServiceDetails(model: new CartModel()),
                    )
                );
```

then in ServiceDetails i didnt get any error
so in build widget

```
@override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return ScopedModel(
        model: widget.model,
        child: Scaffold(...)
      );
     }
```

and i have a cart button which on tap:

```
onTap: () {
   Navigator.of(context).push(
     MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => new Cart()
     ),
  );
},
```

Cart class:

```
class Cart extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CartState createState() => _CartState();
}

class _CartState extends State<Cart> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Your Cart")),
      body:  ScopedModel.of<CartModel>(context, rebuildOnChange: true).cart.length == 0 ?
        Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text("Your cart is empty!",style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.grey))
        ) :
        Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:15),
            child: cartListView()
        )
    );
  }

  Widget cartListView(){
    return ScopedModelDescendant<CartModel>(
        builder: (context, child, model) {
    return ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: ScopedModel.of<CartModel>(context,rebuildOnChange: true).total,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Container(
             child: Image.asset(model.cart[index].fs.image)
           )
       }
)})}
}
```

so when i enter cart page i got an error

```
can't find the correct scoped model
```

anyone help plz